# Multiply select html5 form sends only one result if selected several options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit, parameters

I am trying to use a simple html5 form in Ruby on Rails. My fieldset code:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend><%= question.title %></legend>
  <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="question-<%= question.id %>" value="answer-<%= answer.id %>">
        <%= answer.title %>
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 </fieldset>
```

is displayed correct, and when I select one or several options and submit, I have only one parameter in the request as it were radiobutton form although I selected several variants:

```
{"question-162"=>"answer-467"}
```

How to make this form working correct and send multiply parameters in the submit request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name attribute of the checkbox to `question-<%= question.id %>[]` (adding trailing `[]`), and you will get request parameters like below:

```
{"question-1"=>["answer-1", "answer-3"]}
```